# Having trouble eliminate invalid data points from data scraped from api

Tags: api, for-loop, web-scraping

I would like to use the api of this website (https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/documentation?key=Historical&cat=dataHistoday) to get all daily historical OHCLV back to the date when the coins was issued. I managed to get all data from the api, but since I set allData=true, the api returned all data back the earliest timestamp, However, as some coins are not issued that early, there are many invalid data points with prices all equal to 0.

To get rid of these data points, I tried using for loops to examine the data set and delete those with all prices =0. This doesn't seem to work, can anybody help me with this (to include only data points where prices are not 0)?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def historical_OHLCV():
    url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histoday?fsym=SNT&tsym=USD&allData=true"
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = list(page.json()['Data'].values())[3]
    for dic in data:
        exam_frame= list(dic.values())[1:6]
        if all (int(i)==0 for i in exam_frame):
            data.remove(dic)
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
            return df

allData = historical_OHLCV()
RenderJSON(allData)
print (allData)
```

[my current output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzGUo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps look for a column where you don't expect a zero e.g. close price

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/histoday?fsym=SNT&tsym=USD&allData=true').json()
data = r['Data']['Data']
df = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if float(item['close'])!=0])
print(df)
```

This matches with using volumeto which might be a more logical choice

```
df = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if float(item['volumeto'])!=0])
```